# Analytics showing thousands of results with null appended to the url

Tags: apache-2.2

Looking at analytics for a site I maintain that is powered by Magento I am seeing that every week there are lots of visitors reaching a 404 page and it is because there is null being appended to the url. I am always on the site and have never had this happen and have no idea where these are coming from. Has anyone else encountered this or have any ideas on how I can diagnose how these are being generated?

I asked this on stack and a couple of folks suggested this is result of an automated attack script.  Does anyone here have any other ideas about this?  Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Google Analytics ? , you should look at the javascript code for GA used on the error page.
It is possible that it appends some variable to the URL being displayed, and that this variable equals 'null'.
This could be enough.
But it wouldn't explain why they reach a 404 page.

You may change it as explained [here](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=86927) to get the referral that lead to the error page.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response.  Yes sorry I meant GA.  I would say it is like 1% of our traffic so it can not be contained in the script or I imagine it would be a consistent error.  The reason they reach the 404 is because it is a invalid url when the null is appended.  I just search by title of our Page Not Found to find how people got there and that is where I see all of these url/null

Comment: Do you have a custom trackPageview call on the error page ?
I would encourage you to do so to undersand how they reach this URL with a '/null' at the end